# Magento - several plugins use jquery and override previously loaded plugins

Tags: jquery, magento

I have Magento theme that use jQuery and several plugins. All was ok until I installed several extensions, each includes its own version of jQuery.

My problem is that new jQuery include override jQuery object and erase all previously loaded plugins.

Besides, I notice that 3rd party extensions scripts can be included in the middle of list of my scripts.

So,

1. How i can control scripts order in Magento?
2. If i will use

   ```
   var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
   ```

Will `$j` keep all loaded plugins after some extension load jQuery again?

Comment: What do you mean, "each includes its own version of jQuery?"

Comment: Modules like to include their own version of jQuery within the package. So you install a few modules and all of a sudden you have several copies of jQuery loading at the same time.

Comment: Why exactly do you care about ordering jQuery scripts? If I were in your situation I'd simply delete all but one jQuery library, comment out the locations in layout xml files where they are added, add jQuery library to be loaded in reference default and that's it (or if different extensions use different noConfilct variable names create one aditional javascript file that declares them). This would be far more efficient than leaving all the scripts in there (since they extend the page loading period) and loading order manipulation is a bit tricky...

Comment: Yes, it is possible solution. But i have an extension which i want to distribute to other magento installations. I just dont want to deal with editing layout xml each time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem moving my jQuery library to the js folder and then modifying the path of each extension and it works perfectly.

For a detailed way to do it, let me know the extensions and I'd be happy to help ya.